# Only grey colors of the web app on tablet device

Tags: javascript, php, android, css, https

I am developing a web app for the customer and so far everything looked fine.
Today it came out that their device gets only grey colors while visiting the page. All other websites display proper colors but not this one.
CSS and Javascript are loaded fine, also all external resources - there are no errors.
Structure of the app looks fine - it is only problem with colors which are grey.
That may have something in common with SSL certificates which are causing problems - I am using Let's Encrypt from Certbot but I am not sure.
Web app is running on nginx, Ubuntu.

I can not find anywhere similar problem, hopefully someone can help.

Device they are using is Samsung Galaxy Tab A - brand new (maybe something about settings but that would be strange if only one website gets problems with colors).
[Image of how it looks on the device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNJ3A.jpg)

Comment: Sounds like a device setting to me.

Comment: There is no possible way that this has anything to do with SSL.

Comment: A piece of advice while you trouble shoot... Make sure to clear the browser caches while youre testing! This may cause you unforseen problems.

Comment: Use a browser that can simulate being a tablet user agent and test with that. But this is off topic for SO. Browser developer mode is your best friend (and allows you to handle caching as suggested in another comment.)

Answer (score 1):

Just got it solved - maybe someone will need help so I am posting the solution.
Tablet was brand new and it came out that Google Chrome was not updated but the need of update was not showed.

Second thing (here it can matter) - mixed https/https content. I replaced all external links with "http://" or "https://" with "//" and it looks fine.

Thank you for all answers so far!